# Is there a way to remove subtitles from MKV use pymkv

Tags: python, mkv

I am looking at [the docs](https://pypi.org/project/pymkv/) for pymkv. Based on what I have read, I can't seem to find a way to determine if an MKVTrack is a subtitle track or now. All I want to do is remove all subtitles from a bunch of mkv using python.

Does anyone know if this is possible using pymkv library?

Comment: You can check a way of removing subtitles without pymkv: https://gist.github.com/majora2007/724354d081627cfd96c24b8eefef4ec3
I didn't find any information, how to remove subtitles using pymkv. I think, you need to use something another

Answer (score 0):

I read the docs more carefully and came to the correct solution...

```
for file_path in files:
    print("Processing "+file_path)
    mkv = MKVFile(file_path)
    removed_track = False
    tracks = mkv.get_track()
    for track in tracks:
        if track.track_type == "subtitles":
            mkv.remove_track(track.track_id)
            remove_track = True
            print("removed subtitles")
    if removed_track:
        mkv.mux(file_path)
```